# Grid of table ist not as it should be in tabular environment...how to get rid of white space within lines?

Tags: tables, white-space, grids

I'd like to ask a question concerning tables in LATEX.

I produced a table with LATEX, but the grid is not "closed"...see for example the corner on the top right and also some other lines in the first row...they are not connected to the top horizontal line.

I'd like to ask how to fix this.

I would be thankful for any help.

The table looks as follows:

[image]

My code is as follows:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,twoside,
headsepline, footsepline, chapterprefix=true, unknownkeysallowed    % Linie fuer Kopfzeile,
]{scrbook}
\KOMAoptions{headings=optiontohead}

\usepackage[inner=3cm,outer=3cm,top=1.5cm,bottom=2cm,includeheadfoot, footskip=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{float}

\usepackage{verbatim}

\usepackage{makecell}

\usepackage{boldline, multirow}

\usepackage{caption}   % FIXME
\usepackage{keyval}    % FIXME

\usepackage[english]{babel}   


\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
\usepackage[pdftex,table]{xcolor}

\usepackage[               
pdftex,                 
colorlinks=true,         
pdfstartview=FitV,      
linkcolor=black,         
citecolor=black,         
urlcolor=black,          
bookmarks=true
]{hyperref}
\urlstyle{sf}


\usepackage{ragged2e}

\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{eufrak}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{array,blkarray}
\usepackage{arydshln}
\usepackage{multirow,bigdelim}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\usepackage[arrow, matrix, curve]{xy}
\usepackage{bbm}
\usepackage{arcs}

\usepackage{typearea}


\usepackage{longtable}


\usepackage[autostyle]{csquotes}
\usepackage{adjustbox}


\usepackage{sagetex}



\usepackage[nameinlink,capitalize]{cleveref}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,arrows}
\usepackage{scalefnt}

\begin{document}

\resizebox{12cm}{!}{
\begin{tabular}{|l|c |c | cV{4} c c c|c c|c|c c|c|c|c|}
    \hline
    \multicolumn{2}{|l|}{$G=S_5$} & \multicolumn{2}{cV{4}}{$Q_v$} & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{$\langle 1 \rangle$} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{$C_2$} & $C_2$ & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{$V_4$} & $V_4$ & $C_4$ & $D_8$\\
    \hline
    \multicolumn{2}{|l|}{$p=2$} & \multicolumn{2}{cV{4}}{$N_v$} & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{$S_5$} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{$D_{12}$} & $D_8$ & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{$S_4$} & $D_8$ & $D_8$ & $D_8$\\
    \hline
    %\multicolumn{2}{|l|}{$ $} & \multicolumn{2}{cV{4}}{$ $} & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{$ $} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{$ $} & $ $ & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{$ $} &   &   &  \\%[-2.2ex]
    %\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{ $ $ } & %\multicolumn{2}{cV{4}}{$\overline{N}$} & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{$S_5$} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{$S_3$} & $V_4$ & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{$S_3$} & $C_2$ & $C_2$ & $\langle 1\rangle $\\
    %\hline
    \multicolumn{2}{|l|}{$ $} & \cellcolor{blue!45}$ $ & \cellcolor{orange!45}$ $ & \cellcolor{orange!45}$ $ & \cellcolor{orange!45}$ $ & \cellcolor{orange!45}$ $ & \cellcolor{orange!45}$ $ & \cellcolor{orange!45}$ $ & \cellcolor{orange!45}$ $ & \cellcolor{orange!45}$ $ & \cellcolor{orange!45}$ $ & \cellcolor{orange!45}$ $ & \cellcolor{orange!45}$ $ & \cellcolor{orange!45}$ $\\[-2.3ex]
    \multicolumn{2}{|l|}{$ $} & \cellcolor{blue!45}$P$ & \cellcolor{orange!45}$ n_j \in N_v$ & \cellcolor{orange!45}$1$ & \cellcolor{orange!45}$(123)$ & \cellcolor{orange!45}$(12345)$ & \cellcolor{orange!45}$1$ & \cellcolor{orange!45}$(345)$ & \cellcolor{orange!45}$1$ & \cellcolor{orange!45}$1$ & \cellcolor{orange!45}$(234)$ & \cellcolor{orange!45}$1$ & \cellcolor{orange!45}$1$ & \cellcolor{orange!45}$1$\\
    \Xhline{4\arrayrulewidth}       
    $\chi_1 + \chi_2 + 2\chi_3 + \chi_6 + \chi_7$ & $1$ & \multicolumn{2}{cV{4}}{\cellcolor{blue!45}} & \cellcolor{gray!45}$24$ & \cellcolor{gray!45}$0$ & \cellcolor{gray!45}$4$ & $0$ & $0$ & $0$ & $0$ & $0$ & $0$ & $0$ & $0$\\ 
    $\chi_4 + \chi_5$ & $2$  & \multicolumn{2}{cV{4}}{\multirow{-1}{*}{\cellcolor{blue!45}$\langle 1 \rangle$}} & \cellcolor{gray!45}$8$ & \cellcolor{gray!45}$2$ & \cellcolor{gray!45}$-2$ & $0$ & $0$ & $0$ & $0$ & $0$ & $0$ & $0$ & $0$\\
    $\chi_3 + \chi_6 + \chi_7$ & $3$ & \multicolumn{2}{cV{4}}{\cellcolor{blue!45}} & \cellcolor{gray!45}$16$ & \cellcolor{gray!45}$-2$ & \cellcolor{gray!45}$1$ & $0$ & $0$ & $0$ & $0$ & $0$ & $0$ & $0$ & $0$\\
    \hline
    $\chi_1 + \chi_3 + \chi_6$ & $4$ & \multicolumn{2}{cV{4}}{\cellcolor{blue!45}} & $12$ & $0$ & $2$ & \cellcolor{gray!45}$2$ & \cellcolor{gray!45}$2$ & $0$ & $0$ & $0$ & $0$ & $0$ & $0$\\
    $\chi_4$ & $5$ & \multicolumn{2}{cV{4}}{\multirow{-2}{*}{\cellcolor{blue!45}$C_2$}} & $4$ & $1$ & $-1$ & \cellcolor{gray!45}$2$ & \cellcolor{gray!45}$-1$ & $0$ & $0$ & $0$ & $0$ & $0$ & $0$\\
    \hline  
    $\chi_1 + \chi_2 + \chi_6 + \chi_7$ & $6$ & \multicolumn{2}{cV{4}}{\cellcolor{blue!45}$C_2$} & $12$ & $0$ & $2$ & $0$ & $0$ & \cellcolor{gray!45}$4$ & $0$ & $0$ & $0$ & $0$ & $0$\\
    \hline
    $\chi_1 + \chi_2$ & $7$ & \multicolumn{2}{cV{4}}{\cellcolor{blue!45}} & $2$ & $2$ & $2$ & $0$ & $0$ & $2$ & \cellcolor{gray!45}$2$ & \cellcolor{gray!45}$2$ & $0$ & $0$ & $0$\\
    $\chi_6 + \chi_7$ & $8$  & \multicolumn{2}{cV{4}}{\multirow{-2}{*}{\cellcolor{blue!45}$V_4$}} & $10$ & $-2$ & $0$ & $0$ & $0$ & $2$ & \cellcolor{gray!45}$2$ & \cellcolor{gray!45}$-1$ & $0$ & $0$ & $0$\\
    \hline
    $\chi_1 + \chi_6$ & $9$ & \multicolumn{2}{cV{4}}{\cellcolor{blue!45}$V_4$} & $6$ & $0$ & $1$ & $2$ & $2$ & $2$ & $0$ & $0$ & \cellcolor{gray!45}$2$ & $0$ & $0$\\   
    \hline
    $\chi_1 + \chi_7$ & $10$ & \multicolumn{2}{cV{4}}{\cellcolor{blue!45}$C_4$} & $6$ & $0$ & $1$ & $0$ & $0$ & $2$ & $0$ & $0$ & $0$ & \cellcolor{gray!45}$2$ & $0$\\  
    \hline
    $\chi_1$ & $11$ & \multicolumn{2}{cV{4}}{\cellcolor{blue!45}$D_8$} & $1$ & $1$ & $1$ & $1$ & $1$ & $1$ & $1$ & $1$ & $1$ & $1$ & \cellcolor{gray!45}$1$\\   
    \hline
\end{tabular}}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Remove `\usepackage{arydshln}`. And, by the way, the use of `\scalebox` is generally discouraged, as it causes inconsistent fonts.

Comment: Thank you very much. It worked right away. Thank you also for your other remark. I did not know that. Would you like to turn your comment into an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove `\usepackage{arydshln}`. That's what causes this behaviour.

And, by the way, the use of `\scalebox` is generally discouraged, as it causes inconsistent fonts. Better use LaTeX font commands like `\small`, `\footnotesize`, etc.